# How to display the dialogue css properly in middle of the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to display the dialogue whenever click on hyperlink.If 10 records are there in page the dialogue displaying properly.But if we have 50 records in grid when click on 50th record the pop up position is not good ,to see the popup i need to scrool.Please let me know how to display the popup position exactly when click on anywhere in grid,in that place only i need to show that popup. no need to scroll down to see the popup.

My css :

```
 dlg = dlgdiv.dialog({
                title: 'Details: ' + title,
                height: 650,
                width: 450,
                modal: true,
                resizable: true,
                draggable: true,
                autoOpen: false,        
                position: [400, 50]
            });
```

Comment: What type of CSS this is?Looks like jQuery

Comment: Then write it as jQuery not CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code..

```
dlg = dlgdiv.dialog({
            title: 'Details: ' + title,
            height: 650,
            width: 450,
            margin-left: -225,
            margin-top: -325,
            left: $(document).width() / 2,
            top: $(document).height() / 2,
            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            draggable: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            position: fixed
        });
```

Good Luck..

Comment: in position % is not taking.

Comment: no use more space i am seeing on the top of popup and i am scrolling to see that popup .i don't want to scroll to see that popup whenever click on the hyperlink need to show the popup in that positions.

Comment: When using button control instead of hyperlink i am seeing popup in exact position if page having 50 or 100 records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [position component](http://jqueryui.com/position/).

```
$("#myDialog").position({
   my: "center",
   at: "center",
   of: window
});
```

Please refer [Jquery Documentaion for Position](http://jqueryui.com/position/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split the window in two equal parts, then subtract half of the dialog's width to perfectly center it on  the page, like in the figure below:

```
+--------|--------+
|        |        |
|    +===|===+    | 
|    |   |   |    | 
-------------------
|    |   |   |    | 
|    +===|===+    |
|        |        |
+--------|--------+
```

So you code should look like this:

```
dlg = dlgdiv.dialog({
      title: 'Details: ' + title,
      height: 650,
      width: 450,
      margin-left: -225,
      margin-top: -325,
      left: $(document).width() / 2 - $(this).width() / 2,
      top: $(document).height() / 2 - $(this).height() / 2,
      modal: true,
      resizable: true,
      draggable: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      position: fixed
 });
```